# In Django Generate only s3 client generate_presigned_post with content type for mp4 file upload

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, video, mp4

After uploading the video(**.mp4**) file  S3 metadata sets its  **Content-Type : binary/octet-stream**
when makes my **browser** force to **download** the file instead of **playing** In order to make it play in browser i need to change that content-type **programmatically** to "**video/mp4**" in **django**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After giving lots of hours i come to solution:
{

```
def presign_post_S3_url(self, key=None, is_public=False):
    acl = 'private'

    if is_public:
        acl = 'public-read'
    fields = {"acl": acl, "Content-Type": "video/mp4"}
    conditions = [
        {"acl": acl},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]
    ]
    if key is None:
        return ""
   ##s3_client is boto3.client object
    s3_client = self.get_s3_client()
    if s3_client is None:
        return ""
    data = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket=self.bucket,
        Key=key,
        Fields=fields,
        Conditions=conditions

    )
    return data
```